# Opencart Ajax filter For products

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, opencart2.x

The filter contained Refine search button and the page loads the product according to search.But I want when i check the checkbox the product  should display.This can be acheived by ajax..

Original script Of opencart 2.1.0.2 product filter

```
`<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-filter').on('click', function() {
    filter = [];

    $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
        filter.push(this.value);
    });

    location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
});
//--></script> 
`
```

And I tried using ajax

```
`$(document).on('change','.sort_rang',function(){
    filter = [];

    $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
        filter.push(this.value);
    });
   location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     location: location,
     success: function(data)
     {                  
        $('.products-block').html(data);
     }               
   });
   console.log;
  return false;
});`
```

I am getting the desired result .But It loads the whole page. And how can i use  any loader if possible.

Comment: remove line  of `location`

Comment: By removing the location .Ajax part is not working

Comment: or say `var location = `

Answer (score 0):

`location` is global and changes the browser url. To avoid using global `location` you need to define `location` using `var`

```
$(document).on('change','.sort_rang',function(){
    filter = [];

    $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
        filter.push(this.value);
    });
   var location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     location: location,
     success: function(data)
     {                  
        $('.products-block').html(data);
     }               
   });
   console.log;
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just little change in code.In success function i removed the specific id and its working fine

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change','.sort_rang',function(){
    filter = [];

    $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
        filter.push(this.value);
    });
   location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     location: location,
     success: function(data)
     {                  
        html(data);
     }               
   });
   console.log;
  return false;
});
```

Comment: where .sort_rang comes from?